# Python: Calculating difference of values in a nested list by using a While Loop

Tags: python, list, while-loop, nested

I have a list that is composed of nested lists, each nested list contains two values - a float value (file creation date), and a string (a name of the file).

For example:

```
n_List = [[201609070736L, 'GOPR5478.MP4'], [201609070753L, 'GP015478.MP4'],[201609070811L, 'GP025478.MP4']]
```

The nested list is already sorted in order of ascending values (creation dates). I am trying to use a While loop to calculate the difference between each sequential float value.

For Example: 201609070753 - 201609070736 = 17

The goal is to use the time difference values as the basis for grouping the files.

The problem I am having is that when the count reaches the last value for `len(n_List)` it throws an `IndexError` because `count+1` is out of range.

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I can't figure out how to work around this error. no matter what i try the count is always of range when it reaches the last value in the list.

Here is the While loop I've been using.

```
count = 0

while count <= len(n_List):
    full_path = source_folder + "/" + n_List[count][1]

    time_dif = n_List[count+1][0] - n_List[count][0]


    if time_dif < 100:  
       f_List.write(full_path + "\n")
       count = count + 1 
    else: 
        f_List.write(full_path + "\n")
        f_List.close()
        f_List = open(source_folder + 'GoPro' + '_' + str(count) + '.txt', 'w')
        f_List.write(full_path + "\n")
        count = count + 1
```

PS. The only work around I can think of is to assume that the last value will always be appended to the final group of files. so, when the count reaches `len(n_List - 1)`, I skip the time dif calculation, and just automatically add that final value to the last group. While this will probably work most of the time, I can see edge cases where the final value in the list may need to go in a separate group.

Comment: What folder would you want the last file to go into then?

Comment: the files are actually not going anywhere, I'm just using the time dif calculation to group the files into different lists. The file paths are written out to separate txt files based on the groupings. So in this case the last value would get added to the last line of the last text file.  does that make sense?

Comment: what about the last data?

Comment: You have an algorithm problem.  If you have a list of n values, there will be only n-1 differences between values.  If you want to categorize n objects you can't do it with only n-1 values.  You need to think of a better algorithm.

Comment: The `L` suffix after a number makes it a `long` (a type of integer), not a float.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using zip could be easier to get difference.

```
res1,res2 = [],[]
for i,j in zip(n_List,n_List[1:]):
    target = res1 if j[0]-i[0] < 100 else res2
    target.append(i[1])
```

Comment: @galaxyman, thanks for the help, i agree that a zip function is probably a better way to get the time dif. But I'm still encountering two issues. (1) when `j[0]-i[0]` is 100 or greater this function will write the `i[0]` value to a new group, when really it is the `j[0]` value that should be the beginning of the new group.  (2) I still see an issue when the function gets to the end of the list. the last value on the list is left of the final group, i assume because the `j[0]-i[0]` operation doesn't work when you reach the last time - there is no `j[0]` after it reaches the final `i[0]`

Comment: @vgndc for the first one, you can reverse list after loop finish. the second, what do you want to the last element?

Comment: @galaxyman, the problem with using `reversed()` is that the list values need to be written to .txt file. For example, time dif <100 write value to text-1.txt, at first time dif > 100 start a new text-2.txt. So going in reverse wont really fix what went wrong on the first pass. Values will  have already been written out to the wrong .txt file. For the second, question, try to be more clear, the zip function does not seem to account for uneven pairs in the nested list. so i need to figure a way when the loop reaches the last i,j pair to write that last `j[1]` value to the last .txt file.

Comment: @galaxyman, actually I just realized the first half of my last respond was due to an error in my function. the second part is still unresolved - when the loop reaches the last nested list, i need that last value written out to the last .txt file, even if there is no need to calculate a time dif on the last value in the list.

Answer (score 0):

n_list(len(n_list)) will always return an index out of range error

```
while count < len(n_List):
```

should be enough because you are starting count at 0, not 1.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, here is the solution I used, thanks to @galaxyman for the help.

I handled the issue of the last value in the nested list, by simply
adding that value after the loop completes. Don't know if that's the most
elegant way to do it, but it works.

(note: i'm only posting the function related to the zip method suggested in the previous posts).

```
    def list_zip(get_gp_list): 
        ffmpeg_list = open(output_path + '\\' + gp_List[0][1][0:8] + '.txt', 'a')
        for a,b in zip(gp_List,gp_List[1:]):
            full_path = gopro_folder + '\\' + a[1]
            time_dif = b[0]-a[0]
            if time_dif < 100: 
                ffmpeg_list.write("file " + full_path + "\n")
            else:
                ffmpeg_list.write("file " + full_path + "\n")
                ffmpeg_list.close()
                ffmpeg_list = open(output_path + '\\' + b[1][0:8] + '.txt', 'a') 

    last_val = gp_List[-1][1]
    ffmpeg_list.write("file " + gopro_folder + '\\' + last_val + "\n")
    ffmpeg_list.close()
```